# Image is replaced with URL when I send MMS via Twilio channel in Bot Framework nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio, botframework, azure-bot-service, twilio-programmable-chat

I am configuring a Twilio channel for BOt. I want to send MMS using this Bot to user. But Image which is attached in Bot framework, is replaced with a URL .
Here is How I'm sending the MMS.

```
       fs.readFile(attachmentUrl, function (err, data) {
       var base64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
       var msg = new builder.Message().address(address1)
          .addAttachment({
          contentUrl: util.format('data:%s;base64,%s', contentType, base64),
                   contentType: contentType,
                   name: 'BotFrameworkLogo.png'
                });

           bot.send(msg, function (err, addresses) {
                callback(err, addresses);
           });
    });
```

[image]

Expected Output should be :

[image]

Comment: what is size of the image? hope `contentType` is defined somewhere with proper value, can't see it in your OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be out side of the zone supported for this by twilio.

> MMS messages sent internationally will be converted to SMS text
>   messages with a URL link to the media

from [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179808-Sending-and-receiving-MMS-messages)